# code for skew detection of image in opencv python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, skew

How to convert code for skew detection and correction in image using OpenCV c++ to OpenCV python. I tried to convert the following code but it's not working.

```
Mat src=imread("text.png",0);
Mat thr,dst;
threshold(src,thr,200,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
imshow("thr",thr);

std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = thr.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = thr.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
        points.push_back(it.pos());

cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, box.angle, 1);

//cv::Mat rotated(src.size(),src.type(),Scalar(255,255,255));
Mat rotated;
cv::warpAffine(src, rotated, rot_mat, src.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);
imshow("rotated",rotated);
```

Answer (score 0):

*it is always true. I think you should try

```
if (!thr.at<uchar>(it.pos()))
```

maybe it's your mistake

Comment: After the threshold *it evaluates to either 0 or 255 and is casted correctly as bool